# Что означает выражение "ещё почище"?

Tags: фразеология

**У А.Т. Аверченко есть рассказ для детей "Сережкин рубль" (1922 год).**

Мальчик Сережа, герой рассказа, время от времени  сочинял стихи, причем совершенно футуристические по форме и странные по содержанию, а за свой последний шедевр он даже был наказан и оставлен без сладкого, долго плакал, но потом принес дяде новое произведение.  "Твои стихи? Хорошие? – спросил дядя. "**Да, это уж, брат, почище тех будут"**, – важно сказал Сережка и прочёл: "Люблю грозу в начале мая, летит кибитка удалая ..."

Я думала, что выражение  "еще почище " является  **негативной оценкой, просто мальчик не знает этого.** Но теперь я в этом не уверена. Хотелось бы понять, **как менялось значение фразеологизма и что он означает в современном языке.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не думаю, что это фразеологизм, это просторечное наречие, само по себе многозначное.

Ушаков выделяет 4 значения:

ПОЧИ́ЩЕ, сравн. к прил. и к нареч. (•разг. ).

1. Несколько, немного чище. Выбери лист бумаги почище. Одеться почище.
2. Лучше (•фам.) - Быв еще в гимназии, мальчиком, он уже сочинял стихи - и какие! «Почище того, что теперь пишут.» Григорович. Почище тебя сделаю!
3. Ярче, крепче, более хлесткий или более хлестко (о словах, о речи; •фам. ). Он выразился еще почище прежнего.
4. Важнее, знатнее. «- А семга, а рыба, а котлеты? - Да, это для тех, которые почище-с.» Гоголь.

   Т.Ф. Ефремова  в "Новом словаре русского языка" среди переносных значений указывает следующие:

2)
а) перен. Значительнее, сильнее.
б) Выразительнее, резче (о словах, о речи).

3) перен. Важнее, знатнее.

Так что оценка вполне себе положительная, кроме значения "более хлёстко","резче", потому что у нас отрицательное отношение к резким словам, но вот у Ефремовой оно стоит рядом с "выразительнее", у Ушакова -  с "ярче". Некоторые хлесткие слова действительно яркие, так что, может, и не совсем отрицательное отношение.

Comment: Возможно, это наше современное "покруче".  В Нацкорпусе часто можно встретить негативное значение, например:  Не знаю, ты слышал или нет, но там за Сухаревской туннель, типа, еще почище этого, такая дрянь, мне там еще как-то пробиваться надо будет. [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)]   Ну! Ты еще почище нас! Шантаж ― уголовно наказуемое преступление! [Л. С. Петрушевская. Анданте (1975)]«Этот, ― говорит, ― плут, а тот и еще почище. [Н. С. Лесков. Воительница (1866)]

Comment: Ну да, получается, что это в значении "сильнее", усиливает предыдущую оценку: то плохое, а это ещё хуже.

Comment: Именно: усиливает некую оценку. Безотносительно к знаку этой оценки (+ или -).